# IBM Worklight- Automatically badge increment when Push Notification Arrives

Tags: notifications, push, ibm-mobilefirst, badge

Brothers! I am using Mobilefirst v7 and needs to auto increment the icon badge number when notification arrives into Mobile. currently, when I open the app by tapping on to the notification then my code allow to increment badge number on icon. 
I need this process to be automated. Can anyone please help me out!

Comment: What about the sisters?

Comment: Sorry! Brothers & Sister. I haven't heard any one of them that's why

Answer (score 1):

MobileFirst Platform does not provide any mechanism for updating Badges other than setting or removing. So if you send lots of updates you will need to write such a mechanism on your own in order to control the badge updating.

You can use the [WL.Badge API](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Badge.html?cp=SSHS8R_7.0.0%2F9-0-0-1-4) for this purpose.